# How to save images when navigating in Angular SPA?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using Angular's router to navigate between components, thought when I'm going back, the components reload. I solved the content issue by saving the content array in a service and loading it from there, so it doesn't have to call the server every single time. But I don't know what to do with images, they are received from the server as a base64 string, and then shown in the image, but how do I cache/save them or in what form should I keep them in memory in order to instantly load them again when navigating back to the component that contains them?
I looked online but didn't know what terms to use in order to search for a solution.

Comment: you can save them in `localstorage` as a `string` value , and load them from there

Comment: I wanted to ask if you already tried out my solution provided. I just updated it and you should now see a working result!

Comment: @ProbabilisticCode yep it did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component you are looking for is either `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` (you could also play around with cookies, but I find the previously mentioned ways easier to use):

- Session: Stored until the browser window is open
- Local: Persisted, even when the browser is closed.

Regardless of what kind of these storages you use, the data contained actually is the same, consisting of ***key-value*** pairs.

---

`localStorage` and `sessionStorage` are no built-in Angular features, you can imagine it more like an API provided by *Java/TypeScript*. For a detailed description of this API, have a look at [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

---

You can easily see what a website is storing on your machine by pressing F12 and navigating in the developer options.

---

I have created a simple example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-localstorage-image-cache).